# Export XML data type column with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, export

I have a table with 2 columns. The column response is an XML data type column (I am able to click on it an open the XML document). I would like to have a code that would export each row of the column response into an XML document saved on my desktop. Path = `C:\Users\SAM\Desktop\Folder`.

So I would have an XML document for each row.

Output:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table

 Data           Response
20130101    <Getresponsequ…
20130102    <Getresponsequ…
20130103    <Getresponsequ…
20130104    <Getresponsequ…
20130105    <Getresponsequ…
20130106    <Getresponsequ…
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: This information is already part of your question. But the version of your SQL Server isn't. One more question: Do you have admin rights in your RDBMS? Do you have the right to write into the file system?

Comment: SQL 11. I don't have admin rights in myRDBMS. Thank you

Comment: 11 is the internal number. This is called SQL Server 2012. Without the necessary rights you cannot write your XML out directly from your SQL Server Management Studio. And be aware, that the Server will probably see another machine than you see... You can use BCP (look at the answer of @jhmt) or you could open a connection through ODC (e.g. via Excel or MS Query or any other application which allows you to connect to external data)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bcp Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms162802.aspx) to export query results to xml files.

It can be used from command prompt.

For example:

```
bcp "SELECT Response FROM [DB].dbo.[Table] WHERE Data = '20130101'" queryout "C:\Users\SAM\Desktop\Folder\20130101.xml" -c -S {ServerName} -U sa -P {password}
```